# Discord PY can't change channel where messages are sent

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm using Discord py, but i cant change channel where messages are sent, how its works: first i'm using command !set_channel to set channel ID, this ID is saves in txt document, after this i'm using command "!say bla bla" and this message sends to my setted channel in previous command, in this command before thats execute i'm cutting not needed trash like " ( ) ' " because this trash  breaks my code i think. If i'm not cut code this will look like " ('824312123131822092',) ". I can't understand why i'm getting "none" when i'm trying to send message in setted channel.

1. Yes i'm added my discord bot to my server, my bot only on my server.
2. Yes my channel is created and i'm setted correct ID.

````
@bot.command()
async def say(msg, *arg):
  file1 = open("channel.txt", "r")
  output = file1.read()
  file1.close()
  replaced_output = output.replace("'", "")
  replaced_output2 = replaced_output.replace("(", "")
  replaced_output3 = replaced_output2.replace(")", "")
  replaced_output4 = replaced_output3.replace(",", "")
  channel = bot.get_channel(replaced_output4)
  author = msg.author.id
  if str(author) != str(owner):
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"<@{author}> ```You not have rights.```", colour=COLOR)
    await msg.channel.send(embed=embed)
    return
  else:
    if not arg:
     embed = discord.Embed(description="Required argument after !say", colour=COLOR)
     embed.set_author(name="Omega Software",icon_url=msg.guild.icon_url)
     embed.set_footer(text="Created for fun!")
     await msg.channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
      embed = discord.Embed(description=" ".join(arg), colour=COLOR)
      embed.set_author(name="Omega Software",icon_url=msg.guild.icon_url)
      embed.set_footer(text="Created for fun!")
      print (channel)
      print (replaced_output4)
      if channel:
       await channel.send(embed=embed)
       return
````

Comment: `bot.get_channel()` takes in an int, you're passing it a str. You'll need to type cast the str to int.

Comment: Omg thanks you @Taku! Thats really helped! I'm newcomer in stackoverflow and don't know how to set your comment as answer or upvote your comment.